# Prolog notBetween function

Tags: prolog

I need some help here with Prolog.
So I have this function between that evaluates if an element is between other two.
What I need now is a function that evaluates if a member is not between other two, even if it is the same as one of them.
I tried it :

```
notBetween(X,Y,Z,List):-right(X,Y,List),right(Z,Y,List). // right means Z is right to Y and left the same for the left

notBetween(X,Y,Z,List):-left(X,Y,List),left(Z,Y,List).

notBetween(X,Y,Z,List):-Y is Z;Y is X.
```

I am starting with Prolog so maybe it is not even close to work, so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: You should really show complete programs, how have you defined `right` and `left`? How can we guess where the problem is?

Comment: You keep on claiming that you have a function (predicate maybe?) that evaluates if an element is between two others. Just show it already!

Comment: As an aside, the comment character in Prolog is `%`, not `//`.

Comment: @DanielLyons thank you, I know that but I am just starting Prolog and sometimes I forget !

Comment: This reason is hilarious :) You understand that if anyone else searches Stackoverflow for the same question, and sees the correct answer, they can take it and use it, right? How is that different? And really, the whole point of Stackoverflow is: you show us your code, we show you your mistake. What you expect: you give your free interpretation of an assignment and we give working code. Very bad form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it come to negation, Prolog behaviour must be handled more carefully, because negation is 'embedded' in the proof engine (see [SLD resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution) to know a little more about abstract Prolog). In your case, you are listing 3 alternatives, then if one will *not* be true, Prolog will try the next. It's the opposite of what you need.

There is an operator (\+)/2, read *not*. The name has been chosen 'on purpose' different than not, to remember us that it's a bit different from the *not* we use so easily during speaking.

But in this case it will do the trick:

```
notBeetwen(X,Y,Z,List) :- \+ between(X,Y,Z,List).
```

Of course, to a Prolog programmer, will be clearer the direct use of \+, instead of a predicate that 'hides' it - and requires inspection.

A possibile definition of between/4 with basic lists builtins

```
between(X,Y,Z,List) :- append(_, [X,Y,Z|_], List) ; append(_, [Z,Y,X|_], List).
```

*EDIT*: a simpler, constructive definition (minimal?) could be:

```
notBetween(X,Y,Z, List) :-
  nth1(A, List, X),
  nth1(B, List, Y),
  nth1(C, List, Z),
  ( B < A, B < C ; B > A, B > C ), !.
```

*EDIT*: (==)/2 works with lists, without side effects (it doesn't instance variables). Example

```
1 ?- [1,2,3] == [1,2,3].
true.

2 ?- [1,2,X] == [1,2,X].
true.

3 ?- [1,2,Y] == [1,2,X].
false.
```

Comment: Just to mention a rule of thumb of mine, the number of rules you have for a particular predicate is a good indicator of the number of special cases the question has or answers you expect to get. Intuitively, I would expect a predicate named `not_between` to have exactly one answer, true or false, so I would be somewhat surprised if it took three clauses as it does in the question and not one or two as it does in your solution.

Comment: @DanielLyons: I must use Boole' algebra sometime to understand statements with negation, but Prolog negation can be really difficult to follow. It isn't declarative at all. A known limitation of the language.

Comment: Isn't it more of a limitation of the idea? I don't think another language built on unification is going to have a much better negation story—does Mercury?

Comment: @DanielLyons: yes, the problem is rooted in the idea (SLDNF). If only we could avoid to negate anything ... :) In Prolog - because of its power - side effects are harder to follow - and debug.

Comment: @CapelliC Thank you for your help ! Maybe I did not explain well. What I am doing is trying to solve a problem, I need to define some predicates and I defined them all except the notBetween. With those predicates my program should get clues (like A is between B and C, C is not between A and B, B is right to A, etc..) and then fill a list with the final positions. It does all that but once notBetween does not work, it does not fill it right. Your solution does not work, even if I use your between. How can I compare two members to see if they are the same ?== ?Sorry if those are stupid questions

Comment: without left, right definitions it's not possible to answer. See last Boris' comment.

Comment: @CapelliC thank you again, that definition you edited helped a lot. One thing, == works to compare lists ?

Comment: @Boris I know you are right ! Thank you and I am sorry if I am doing it wrong ! Do you know if I can use == to compare lists ?

Comment: @CapelliC just one more question, as you did B<A could I do B == A to refer to them being equal ?

Comment: Yes, of course, use whatever condition fits your requirements. What can be debatable, it's the cut after the test. I mean that - where there are duplicate elements, expressing the conditions become more *blurry*. The cut is a *big* simplification.